Stalemate in Catan
My friends and I tried to come up with some variation of endgames where no player can reasonably make progress. Our discussion came down to almost all players having no settle spots remaining, and the person with Longest Road has to have almost no viable settlements, but blocks every other players' settlements.
Here are all the points to be considered:

5 victory points
Longest Road
Largest Army
Cities (any settlement that has been placed can be assumed to be convertible to a city over infinite turns)

Of course, the game need not be what reasonable players would do, I just want to see if it is theoretically possible, and couldn't find anyone discussing this. For context, we are playing on the standard board with 4 players.
EDIT: I guess we do have one variation, but I'd love to see if there are more realistic setups ending in stalemate!

Yes, it is possible to wind up in a game state where it is impossible for any player to win. Consider the following board position (assume non-red players haven't built any roads beyond their initial placement, which don't really matter):

Each player has only 2 settlements/cities, and cannot build any more for the rest of the game - red has used all their roads but has no access to a buildable location, while all the other players are boxed in by red's roads.
Red could get 4 points from cities and 2 from the longest road, but they would require drawing victory points and knights to win, which is not guaranteed. Furthermore, we can distribute the outstanding 7 points unaccounted for by the board state (5 victory points cards, 2 largest army) among the remaining 3 players, and have none of them reach 10 points as well. There are many distributions of the knight and victory points cards that will result in no one ever reaching 10 points from the pictured board state.
By limiting everyone to only 2 cities, there can only be a maximum of 25 points total scored by all players over the course of the game (2 points x 2 cities x 4 players + 2 longest road + 2 largest army + 5 VP cards), which are easily distributed among 4 players so that no one reaches 10 points. In the absolute worst "farthest from victory" case, three players score 6 points and one scores 7.
It would be rather difficult to get into a stalemate scenario naturally. It would basically require players making no attempt to expand rationally, and for one player to spend all their roads without ever reaching a buildable location. It would also require a rather unlucky distribution of the VP and knight cards.
A few notes on what guarantees or rules out a stalemate: Any board state with at least 37 points total must have at least one player with 10 points. 9 of these points from the Largest Army, Longest Road, and VP cards are "guaranteed" to be given out at some point, so all we can do is limit the number of points from settlements/cities to under 28 total - this means we can have no more than 13 cities total. It is possible for one player (but no more) to get 4 cities and for there still to be a stalemate - this would leave three players with 3 cities each, one of which has Longest Road, one which has Largest Army, and one of which has 2 VP cards, while the remaining player has 4 cities, and the remaining 3 VP cards are distributed one apiece to any of the 4 players. This "closest to victory" stalemate yields scores of 9, 9, 9, and 8, which is the maximum possible stalemating total of 35 points (since there's no way to hit 36, as any additional settlement would eventually be upgraded for an additional point - there's no way to score a 36th point without allowing a 37th).

Maybe we need some option to deconstruct a road (with more payment, of course)?

@PaŭloEbermann: I'm unconvinced. This is a highly implausible map for players who are actually trying to win the game. Even if we presume that Red controls all of the wood and brick on the map, and that nobody else has enough alternative resources to make sea trade viable (which requires very poor initial placement by the other three players), Red's decision to thoroughly block everyone in (instead of doing a little early blocking, then building to the southeast to enable more settlements) is completely nonsensical play.

@Kevin To add to your comment, Red could've built the last two roads on the edges downward along the coasts instead of going to green and blue settlements. This gives him two places for settlements and later cities, which gives him the victory together with the longest road. So yes, it's a purely hypothetical scenario which won't happen if players are actually trying to win.

@Malcolm Indeed, on top of that, the 5 road hairpin loop red has built in the middle of the board serves no purpose whatsoever - it doesn't block anyone from settling, or prevent them from reaching any settle-able locations. If a game of Catan actually wound up in a stalemate, the players almost certainly brought it on themselves.

"the game need not be what reasonable players would do" guys. OP isn't asking for a realistic outcome, just a possible one.

@MichaelW. They're pointing out that it's unrealistic to explain why Paulo's suggestion isn't really necessary, not to critique the answer itself; that's why Nuclear Hoagie pointed out an aspect of his own answer.

This reminds me of the great Donald X quote when asked about how to handle a situation where Dominion devolves into a stalemate because all players made intentionally dumb decisions that cause no one to be able to win: "I guess everyone keeps playing until they starve to death. Always play in a 24-hour restaurant, that's my advice."
